# Ext4 Superblock Corrupted After Fsck

Tags: ext4, data-recovery

An ext4 filesystem was damaged. So I ran fsck against that partition. However, after fsck was completed, I still couldn't mount the filesystem. And now it's reporting superblock corrupted.

```
[root@os1 ~]# mount /dev/sda2 /mnt
mount: /mnt: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda2, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
[root@os1 ~]# fsck /dev/sda2
fsck from util-linux 2.32.1
e2fsck 1.45.4 (23-Sep-2019)
ext2fs_open2: Bad magic number in super-block
fsck.ext2: Superblock invalid, trying backup blocks...
fsck.ext2: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sda2

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
 or
    e2fsck -b 32768 <device>
```

Tried to recover from the backup superblock by looking up the backup superblocks (`mkfs.ext4 -n /dev/sda2`) and used `e2fsck -b superblocks /dev/sda2` to recover. However, it always returns the same error message.

What shall I do now?

Comment: "mkfs.ext4 -n /dev/sda2" tells you how the OS would create a new filesystem on the device - not what it can read from the device. You want `dumpe2fs /dev/sda2 | grep superblock`

Comment: If the filesystem is still corrupt after a successful `fsck`, I'd suspect something is **really really** wrong with your hardware. So the first thing to do is to check the hardware. What kind of storage medium is it? Harddisk, SSD, USB flash drive? There are e.g. cheap chinese USB flash drives with "fake" capacity, if you got one of those, unfortunately your data has overwritten itself.